# Tooltip : Mapping list of Tooltip values to list of functions while plotting

Tags: plotting, functions, tooltip

How is it possible to map a list of Tooltip values to the functions being plotted?

For example:
Assume, f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]... are functions defined.
{t1, t2, t3, ...} are the list of tool-tips to display.

Then to plot:
Plot[ Tooltip[{f1[x], f2[x], ... }], {x, a, b}];
Which will just display the functions as tool-tip
OR
Plot[ {Tooltip[f1[x], t1], Tooltip[f2[x], t2], ...... }, {x, a, b}]

Which is the required behavior, but, is there another shorter or direct way of mapping the functions f1, f2, f3, ... to t1, t2, t3, .... rather than manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
funcs = {Sin[x], Cos[x], Sin[x] Cos[x]};
tips = {"t1", "t2", "t3"};

Plot[Thread[Tooltip[funcs, tips]], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Evaluated -> True]
Plot[Evaluate@Thread[Tooltip[funcs, tips]], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
Plot[Evaluate@MapThread[Tooltip, {funcs, tips}], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
Plot[Tooltip @@@ Transpose[{funcs, tips}], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Evaluated -> True]
```

all give

[image]

Comment: I've never seen the `Evaluated` option before.  Is it undocumented?

Comment: @2012rcampion, it is undocumented as of version 9.0.1.0; don't know if version 10 has it documented. See [other appearances of Evaluated on this site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Evaluated-%3ETrue)

Comment: Nice, it works.